# Is it possible to get data from one page and send it to another which opens on click?

Tags: php

I want to display username of the user when he click on button this username should be displayed on window.php only when this window.php pops up when I click on a text "click to open window" also the user shouldnt be redirected to any other page.Is this possible?Somebody told me to use javascript someone else said to use $_post $_get method but I dont find relevate tutorials on youtube.Please any suggestion,document,tutorial would be helpful.

i tried this on first page

```
    <?php

if (($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $url = "window.php";
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit();
} else if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'] ;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $url = "window.php";
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit();


}
?>
```

and this on second page

```
<?php session_start();?> <?php require('db.php'); ?> <?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){ header("Location: "); exit(); } $username = $_SESSION['username']; $url = "window.php?username=" . $username; echo "hello $username <a href='$url'>home</a>"; ?>
```

I cant start a session on first page because one is already running is this breaking the connection for session_start() on page 2?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: should i use javascript or $_post method?do you have any example?

Comment: Nope, I dont have any example, but in Google has a lot of examples. The best way is to start your own example, and if u got any problems, you can ask here in SO with your example, then someone will help u, for sure :)

Comment: Yes. Both. You are going to route the browser to your other php file using javascript and `post` your variables to it. In that php you are going to read those variables using `$_POST` array in your php.

Comment: i tried already one tutorial with $_post method but wasnt even close to what I need and was the only one related to passing variables

Comment: Then show us what you already tried :)

Comment: <?php

    if (($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $url = "window.php";
        header('Location: ' . $url);
        exit();
    } else if (isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'] ;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $url = "window.php";
        header('Location: ' . $url);
        exit();


    }
    ?>

Comment: im just a beginner to php if anyone has some easy tutorial for my problem please share it,thank you

Comment: @AlexPop I think you have a larger "how do I architect a web app" question here. The easiest answer to the basic question is Javascript, but usually some kind of "session" is used to track that sort of data by the backend.

Comment: @AlexBarker can I do something like giving my button js function to get database data and also to send it on the second page using onclick function?

Comment: You "can," however, it would be easier in the long run to save persistent data in a PHP session and then retrieve that data before rendering each page.  Most web applications are built around the [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) concept.  You should probably do some reading and use a framework that already lays out these principals.